# What are the different semantics of the curly brace in C++ (as per specification)

Tags: c++, c++11, curly-braces

**Question**

What are the different semantics of the curly brace? considering C++ specification (ISO/IEC 14882:2011 or further)

**Further explanation:**

For instance, brace can be used in many circumstances, some of them seem similar while other don't:

```
namespace ns{}       // namespace scope
int func(){}         // function-body
[&](){};             // Lambda body
class A{};           // Class/struct declaration
enum E{};            // Enum declaration
union U{};           // Union declaration
{}                   // in-function scope
if(){}               // conditional and loop scope
try{}catch(...){}    // exception 
T array[]{};         // uniform initialization list

...
```

Which is the complete list of **different** uses of curly brace?

*With different, I refer for example to the in-function scope which is probably the same semantic than the conditional/loop semantic.*

Comment: Actually there are only two distinct situations. OK three, because namespace is different from a normal scope block.

Comment: Scope, initialization-list, code-block, namespace code-block? that seem already 4

Comment: I'd count _scope_ and _code block_ the same.

Comment: Broadly speaking, four: *compound-statement*, class/namespace/enum definition and `extern "C"` (or other *linkage-specification*) blocks, *braced-init-list*, and inside an attribute where it can do god (well, implementation)-knows-what.

Comment: So the fact that `int func() return 0;` is invalid is only because function declarations require a mandatory scope?

Comment: Function *definitions* require a *compound-statement*, yes.

Comment: Different in terms of semantic or grammatic? Semantic differences up to what level of detail? Aggregate initialization vs constructor call? Copy vs direct initialization? Or scope establishment vs initialization? Or statement vs expression? I'm inclined to close with "too broad"

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Good point, syntax vs semantic. I am just trying to get a synthetic coverage of this lexer, mainly to understand where to dig deeper. So the answer is probably: semantic (which implicitly also include grammatic), but low detail level. Specific compiler implementation details are far outside of this question.